# Click on brand name and send it to another page

Tags: php

I'm having trouble sending a brand name to another page.

I have this code:

```
$data = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12");
while ($info=mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $output .= '<article class="indibrand">';
    $output .='<li>';
    $output .='<a href="brandproducts.php?brand=". $info["brand"].">';
    $output.=$info["brand"];
    $output.= '</a>';
    $output.='</li>';
    $output.='</article>';
}
```

So when i click on a brand link, the brand name should be passed to brandproducts.php, but when i actually click on a brand name it takes me to brandproducts.php but does not pass the brand name. So the address bar just says `http://site/brandproducts.php?brand=`

Comment: I'm all for the downvoting system, when someone gets downvoted it lets them know that they have made a silly post, have not done enough research or the post is lacking in some other area. but I do feel that the downvoter should have to explain their reason for the downvote. Otherwise how are us uneducated fools going to learn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using incorrect quotes,

```
$output .='<a href="brandproducts.php?brand='. $info["brand"] . '">';
```

Comment: Still not sending it!

Comment: Post your result html here.